# Openshift origin application with JBoss developer studio

Tags: openshift-origin, jboss-developer-studio

I am using openshift origin and JBoss developer studio 9 
When i am trying to create new application using oc new-app in open shift command it working well but when i tried to create any project with jboss studio it give me the following error

"the body of the request was in an unknown format - accepted media types include: application/json, application/yaml
Could not create resource res in namespace '': {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"the body of the request was in an unknown format - accepted media types include: application/json, application/yaml","reason":"UnsupportedMediaType","code":415}"

Please note that this error occurred also when i tried to deploy an image from openshift and i am using all in one openshift origin vm 
Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to update your release of developer studio which relies upon the openshift-restclient-java.  https://github.com/openshift/openshift-restclient-java/pull/112 resolved an issue where the content-type was not being set.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Comment: @Jeff From where i can update it? i just using it from jboss developer studio